# Relative Positioning of Circular Diagram, TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making a metabolism schematic for one of my courses and am having trouble positioning the arrows in my circular diagram (Citric acid cycle) below a box called pyruvate. Much of the code for the citric acid cycle was taken from online but I don't know how to shift both the boxes and arrows downwards. [image].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{Glycolysis} = [rectangle, text centered, draw=black, fill=none, inner sep=0pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [Glycolysis] (Initial) {Pyruvate};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {9}
\def \radius {6cm}
\def \margin {8}

\foreach \molecule [count=\s] in {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}
{
  \node[draw, rectangle, below = 5cm of Initial] at ({360/\n * (\s)}:\radius) {\molecule};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius)
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Get rid of `below = 5cm of Initial` — not sure why you need that. Also, I'd just use one tikzpicture block.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I added in `at (0,0)` to pyruvate as suggested and added `yshift` to both `\node` and `\draw`

Comment: @Justin This may help you: https://plantgenerations.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/latex-the-citric-cycle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `below=5cm of Initial` and place a `\vfill` between the two `tikzpicture` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{Glycolysis/.style={rectangle, text centered, draw=black, fill=none, inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [Glycolysis] (Initial) {Pyruvate};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {9}
\def \radius {6cm}
\def \margin {8}

\foreach \molecule [count=\s] in {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}
{
  \node[draw, rectangle] at ({360/\n * (\s)}:\radius) {\molecule};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius)
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you could put everything in one `tikzpicture`, and position the `Pyruvate` node well above the circle, with e.g. `\node [Glycolysis] (Initial) at (-5,12) {Pyruvate};`. The center of the circle is at `(0,0)`, and the default unit vectors are 1cm, so the node is placed 5cm to the left and 12cm above the center of the circle. Adjust to your preference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{Glycolysis/.style={rectangle, text centered, draw=black, fill=none, inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [Glycolysis] (Initial) at (-5,12) {Pyruvate};

\def \n {9}
\def \radius {6cm}
\def \margin {8}

\foreach \molecule [count=\s] in {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}
{
  \node[draw, rectangle] at ({360/\n * (\s)}:\radius) {\molecule};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius)
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As a sidenote, if you just need a rectangle around a word for the first node, you can use `\framebox`, so an alternative route could be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{Glycolysis/.style={rectangle, text centered, draw=black, fill=none, inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}
\framebox{Pyruvate}

\vfill

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {9}
\def \radius {6cm}
\def \margin {8}

\foreach \molecule [count=\s] in {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}
{
  \node[draw, rectangle] at ({360/\n * (\s)}:\radius) {\molecule};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius)
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to force the arrows to line up with the boxes instead? I want the diagram to be on the bottom half of the page if possible while leaving pyruvate at the top.

Comment: @Justin See edited post.